# UIView subclassing - how to block default drawRect method

Tags: uiview, replace, nib, drawrect

I have the following task.
I have set up a UIView in InterfaceBuilder and set it my own UIView subclass which I use do draw this view with rounded corners and a line around it. What I want to have, is to layout my view in interface builder: set size, position, background color, and then use this information in my drawRect method.
But when I run it I have at first a standard drawn view - just a filled rectangle, and then my rounded rect is drawn over it. Why isn't the plain filled rect replaced by my rect with rounded corners?